# VIM Auto Complete Navigation

Tags: vim, vi

I've disabled the arrow keys on my `.vimrc`, but...

How do I navigate up and down in autocomplete pop-ups? <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> doesn't work as I am in the Insert mode.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (which are conveniently close to everything else). Incidentally, these also work in bash and other useful places, so are good to get used to.

Comment: Wow! That's fast! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You may also like other popupmenu commands: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#popupmenu-keys